# How to enable redirect in Drupal 9 on launch of application

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have enabled Keycloak authentication in a website built with Drupal. As soon as I launch the website I want to redirect to Keycloak's login page if the user is not signed in.

Is there any way to achieve this as soon as I open the website

I tried making the default front page of Drupal website as localhost:8080 (which is where Keycloak's login page is present) but was unable to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experienced with writing custom modules, you can write your own implementation of event subscriber. Here is a good example of it:

> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223109/5644

If not, then I recommend the module https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect - I am not 100 per cent sure if it lets you to specify redirect only for anonymous but it is definitely worth trying.

I am assuming that the integration with the Keycloak service is working and out of scope of this question.